# how to fetch value from grouped form fields after ajax is fired under conditional select type

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

> I also used dpm($form_state->getValue('input_select','text'));
>   and dpm($form_state->getValue('input_select','body'));its after the ajax handler is called...

what is the right way to fetch value for grouped form fields in drupal 8 ?
and I need to achieve this programmatically not via modules

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class Untitled extends FormBase
{
    public function getFormId()
    {
        return 'Mymodule_test_form';
    }

    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $form = array();

        $form['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title of the field'),
    '#description' => t('Enter the Desired title'),
    '#size' => 60,
    '#required' => true,
     '#default' => ($form_state->isValueEmpty('title')) ? null : $form_state->getValue('title'),
  );

        $form['type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Type'),
    '#description' => t('Add or edit'),
    '#options' => array_combine(array(t('Add'), t('Edit')), array(t('Add'), t('Edit'))),
    '#default' => ($form_state->isValueEmpty('type')) ? 'Add' : $form_state->getValue('type'),
    '#required' => true,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '::ajax_handler',
      'wrapper' => 'input-fields',
    ),

  );

        $form['input_select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => ['id' => 'input-fields'],
  );

        $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Create'),
  );

        return $form;
    }

    public function ajax_handler(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        if (($form_state->getValue('type')) === ('Add')) {
            $form['input_select']['text'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => t('Title of the add Block'),
          '#description' => t('Enter the Desired title'),
          '#size' => 60,
          '#required' => true,
          //how to get value of field text if add is selected
           '#default' => ($form_state->isValueEmpty('text')) ? null : $form_state->getValue('text'),
        );
        }

        if ($form_state->getValue('type') === ('Edit')) {
            $form['input_select']['body'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textarea',
            '#title' => t('Title of the edit Block'),
            '#description' => t('Enter the Desired feedback'),
            '#size' => 60,
            '#required' => true,
            //how to get value of field body if edit is selected
             '#default' => ($form_state->isValueEmpty('body')) ? null : $form_state->getValue('body'),
          );
        }

        return $form['input_select'];
    }
}
```

thank-you for your efforts

Comment: In your `$form['type']` the `['#options']` array must be a key value. Sure you've done this, but translate a key is really necessary? Make sure when use `===` operator, sometimes its not needed. By the way check this answer (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/200201/54619), there is something like you asking (container that change its values when select change).