# Use custom field in header (Another region)

Tags: theming, 8, nodes

I'm new to drupal 8. I have a content with couple of custom fields in it. Let's say its name is **Title In Header**. So whenever you need to add new content you have to fill this too.

Now this whole content is in **Content Block** (And Content Block is in Content region).

My template has Header region, Content region and Footer region.

My problem is that I want to have access to that custom field (Title In Header) in a block in header region. But I don't know how to do this and what block should I use to add it in header region. I think it's not a good approach to add another Content Block in Header region to show just a custom field as it shows the whole content. So what should I do?

Comment: Create a separate view mode for the field, see this great answer from @Kevin https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/239370/47547